# Nodejs: How to Live streaming by rtmp or hls?

Tags: node.js, streaming, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I found this solution for live streaming by Nodejs: http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets

But, i dont want use websocket to live stream, i try to get stream from client. But i don't know, how to use this data to stream by rtmp or hls.

Answer (score 0):

follow the nginx-rtmp-module by arut: `https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives`
on more information on how to set up, check out abdisalancodes tutorials on a basic hls streaming setup

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32879084)